# DVD with damaged frames

Tags: audio, video, frame-rate, dvd, mencoder

I have a few damaged DVDs. MEncoder can skip damaged frames. But if output have less frames then input, audio not correspondend with video... Video is delayed... How can I ask MEncoder for correctly set FPS, if it skip any frame during converting? (OS UnixWare)
I try it:

mencoder -fps 20000/1001 -ofps 20000/1001 -oac lavc -ovc lavc ./VTS_04_1.VOB -o dh4.avi

It works only for beginning of the video - after a while the video will start delaying... (I must use +/- keys in Mplayer...)

Or what other converter can skip damaged frames and correctly set the FPS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-vf harddup` to skip duplicate frames and remove `-fps 20000/1001 -ofps 20000/1001`. Mencoder can parse the file fps correctly